# Inserting Rows in Data Frame based on conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, lubridate

I have to split both the start and end dates into intervals of 30 days, and derive two new variables “split start date” and “split end date”.

I tried many things ,but did not work...

```
df_actual <- data.frame(
  order_id = "a", 
  start_date="01/05/2017", 
  ends_with="06/07/2017"
)


df_expected  <- data.frame(
  order_id = rep("a", 3), 
  start_date = rep("01/05/2017", 3), 
  ends_with = rep("06/07/2017", 3),
  split_start_date = c("01/05/2017", "31/05/2017", "30/06/2017"), 
  split_end_date = c("30/05/2017", "29/06/2017", "06/07/2017")
)
```

Comment: It would be very useful whether you share your attempts in order to understand how to help you

Answer (score 0):

I increased your example to include 2 order_ids to see what happens if there are more than 1 id.

I created a function called my_fun, see section function. In this function I take the start_date and create new start_dates based on the difference between the start_date and end_withs divided by the duration. This gives the new dates that need to be created. after the split_start dates have been created, the split_end dates are just a fill in exercise, taking care to deduct 1 day to get to your example output.

Using `map2` with `setNames` and `bind_rows` creates a data.frame with the new dates and order_id as identifier. this can then be joined with the original table to create the expected output.

### Edit:

added code to function to deal with edge cases like `NA` in the dates or when start_date equals ends_with.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df_actual %>% 
  inner_join(map2(df_actual$start_date, df_actual$ends_with, my_fun) %>% 
               setNames(., df_actual$order_id) %>% 
               bind_rows(., .id = "order_id"))

  order_id start_date  ends_with split_start  split_end
1        a 2017-05-01       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>
2        b 2016-05-01 2016-07-06  2016-05-01 2016-05-30
3        b 2016-05-01 2016-07-06  2016-05-31 2016-06-29
4        b 2016-05-01 2016-07-06  2016-06-30 2016-07-06
5        c 2017-07-01 2017-07-01  2017-07-01 2017-07-01
6        d       <NA> 2017-07-01        <NA>       <NA>
```

function:

```
my_fun <- function(x, y, duration = 30) {
  d <- ddays(duration)
  
  if(is.na(x) | is.na(y)) split_start <- split_end <- NA else 
    if(x == y) {
      split_start <- x
      split_end <- y
      } else {
        n <- (y - x) %/% d 
        
        split_start <- c(rep(x, n + 1))
        
        for(i in 1:n+1){
          split_start[i] <- x + (i - 1) * d
        }
        
        split_end <- split_start[1:n+1]
        split_end <- split_end - ddays(1)
        split_end[n+1] <- y
        }

  df <- data.frame(split_start, split_end)
  return(df)
}
```

data:

```
df_actual <- structure(list(order_id = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), start_date = structure(c(17287, 
16922, 17348, NA), class = "Date"), ends_with = structure(c(NA, 
16988, 17348, 17348), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution , I ran the code and it gave me this error                "Error in rep.default(x, n + 1) : invalid 'times' argument "

Comment: @YogeshKumar, I retested everything in 2 different r versions. No issues at all. I think the problem is that one or both of your dates has no values or `NA`.

Comment: Thanks a lot , really appreciate it

Comment: @YogeshKumar, see edit to deal with edge cases like `NA`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)

df_actual<-data.frame(order_id="a",start_date="01/05/2017",ends_with="06/07/2017")
start_date <- dmy(as.character(df_actual[1,2]))
ends_with <- dmy(as.character(df_actual[1,3]))

day_number <- as.numeric(difftime(ends_with, start_date))

batch_duration = 30

no_batches <- ceiling(day_number / batch_duration)
remainder <- day_number %% batch_duration + 1#for last day

batches <- rep(batch_duration, no_batches)
if(remainder > 0){
  batches[no_batches] <- remainder
}

new_cols <- data.frame(split_start_date=character(), split_end_date=character())
prev_end_date <- start_date - 1
for(i in 1:no_batches){
  split_end_date <- start_date + (i-1) * batch_duration + (batches[i]-1)
  split_start_date <- prev_end_date + 1
  prev_end_date <- split_end_date
  data_frame_row <- data.frame(split_start_date, split_end_date)
  new_cols <- rbind(new_cols, data_frame_row)
}

# print(new_cols)
print(cbind(df_actual, new_cols))
```